# What is the efficient, standards-compliant mechanism for processing Unicode using C++17?

Tags: c++, unicode, encoding, locale, utf

**Short version:**
If I wanted to write program that can efficiently perform operations with Unicode characters, being able to input and output files in UTF-8 or UTF-16 encodings. What is the appropriate way to do this with C++?

**Long version:**
C++ predates Unicode, and both have evolved significantly since. I need to know how to write standards-compliant C++ code that is leak-free. I need a clear answers to:

- Which string container should I pick?

  - `std::string` with UTF-8?
  - `std::wstring` (don't really know much about it)
  - `std::u16string` with UTF-16?
  - `std::u32string` with UTF-32?
- Should I stick entirely to one of the above containers or change them when needed?
- Can I use non-english characters in string literals, when using UTF strings, such as Polish characters: `ąćęłńśźż` etc?
- What changes when we store UTF-8 encoded characters in `std::string`? Are they limited to one-byte ASCII characters or can they be multi-byte?
  What happens when i do the following?

  ```
   std::string s = u8"foo";
   s += 'x';
  ```
- What are differences between wchar_t and other multi-byte character types? Is `wchar_t` character or `wchar_t` string literal capable of storing UTF encodings?

Comment: One question per question please. As-is this is way too broad for SO format.

Comment: It's an interesting topic though - where should it go instead?

Comment: I know that this is huge topic and I may be wrong, but asking these questions separately would take ages. In my opinion they are linked to each other. I am quite a newbie in SO, forgive me please.

Comment: @razzorflame I suggest breaking it down into multiple questions. After doing the proper online research, that is.

Comment: *"If I wanted to write ideally a bug free program"* - Let go of this notion, it's impossible. You are not Jon Skeet.

Comment: @StoryTeller, sorry that should look like this: "... to write, ideally, a bug free program".

Comment: If a program needs to process unicode characters (like perform regex or replacements, editing etc..) then I usually convert everything to `UTF-32` and work with that internally. Otherwise `UTF-8` for `i/o` and display. Using `GUI` toolkits may force you to work with a particular encoding. Some `UTF-16` others `UTF-8` etc...

Comment: This was a useful resource for me when dealing with Unicode in C++: http://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: Take a few secs to think about left-to-right vs right-to-left; what exactly is a space ( https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180214-00/?p=98016 ); what sort of text processing are you going to do?  The storage problem (any of the UTFs) is not the end of the issue just the beginning.  eg your toupper / tolower does not make sense for some languages which will not round-trip (eg German) or even have a conversion.

Comment: There's no usable Unicode support in the C++ standard. The problem is solved with third party libraries and frameworks.

Comment: So why L"", u8"", u"" and U"" string literals exist? cppreference clearly says about UTF.

Comment: @razzorflame: they exist because they are necessary to encode Unicode string literals in the app's memory.  But **using** Unicode data at runtime is a huge can of worms, requiring many logistics beyond just in-memory representation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Which string container should I pick?

That is really up to you to decide, based on your own particular needs.  Any of the choices you have presented will work, and they each have their own advantages and disadvantages.  Generically, UTF-8 is good to use for storage and communication purposes, and is backwards compatible with ASCII.  Whereas UTF-16/32 is easier to use when processing Unicode data.

> `std::wstring` (don't really know much about it)

The size of `wchar_t` is compiler-dependent and even platform-dependent.  For instance, on Windows, `wchar_t` is 2 bytes, making `std::wstring` usable for UTF-16 encoded strings.  On other platforms, `wchar_t` may be 4 bytes instead, making `std::wstring` usable for UTF-32 encoded strings instead.  That is why `wchar_t`/`std::wstring` is generally not used in portable code, and why `char16_t`/`std::u16string` and `char32_t`/`std::u32string` were introduced in C++11.  Even `char` can have portability issues for UTF-8, since `char` can be either signed or unsigned at the descretion of the compiler vendors, which is why `char8_t`/`std::u8string` was introduced in C++20 for UTF-8.

> Should I stick entirely to one of the above containers or change them when needed?

Use whatever containers suit your needs.

Typically, you should use one string type throughout your code.  Perform data conversions only at the boundaries where string data enters/leaves your program.  For instance, when reading/writing files, network communications, platform system calls, etc.

> How to properly convert between them?

There are many ways to handle that.

C++11 and later have `std::wstring_convert`/`std::wbuffer_convert`. But these were deprecated in C++17.

There are 3rd party Unicode conversion libraries, such as ICONV, ICU, etc.

There are C library functions, platform system calls, etc.

> Can I use non-english characters in string literals, when using UTF strings, such as Polish characters: `ąćęłńśźż` etc?

Yes, if you use appropriate string literal prefixes:

`u8` for UTF-8.

`L` for UTF-16 or UTF-32 (depending on compiler/platform).

`u16` for UTF-16.

`u32` for UTF-32.

Also, be aware that the charset you use to save your source files can affect how the compiler interprets string literals. So make sure that whatever charset you choose to save your files in, like UTF-8, that you tell your compiler what that charset is, or else you may end up with the wrong string values at runtime.

> What changes when we store UTF-8 encoded characters in `std::string`? Are they limited to one-byte ASCII characters or can they be multi-byte?

Each string character may be a single-byte, or be part of a multi-byte representation of a Unicode codepoint. It depends on the encoding of the string, and the character being encoded.

Just as `std::wstring` (when `wchar_t` is 2 bytes) and `std::u16string` can hold strings containing supplementary characters outside of the Unicode BMP, which require UTF-16 surrogates to encode.

When a string container contains a UTF encoded string, each "character" is just a UTF encoded codeunit.  UTF-8 encodes a Unicode codepoint as 1-4 codeunits (1-4 `char`s in a `std::string)`.  UTF-16 encodes a codepoint as 1-2 codeunits (1-2 `wchar_t`s/`char16_t`s in a  `std::wstring`/`std::u16string`).  UTF-32 encodes a codepoint as 1 codeunit (1 `char32_t` in a `std::u32string`).

> What happens when i do the following?
>
> ```
> std::string s = u8"foo";
> s += 'x';
> ```

Exactly what you would expect.  A `std::string` holds `char` elements.  Regardless of encoding, `operator+=(char)` will simply append a single `char` to the end of the `std::string`.

> How can I distinguish UTF `char[]` and non-UTF `char[]` or `std::string`?

You would need to have outside knowledge of the string's original encoding, or else perform your own heuristic analysis of the `char[]`/`std::string` data to see if it conforms to a UTF or not.

> What are differences between wchar_t and other multi-byte character types?

Byte size and UTF encoding.

`char` = ANSI/MBCS or UTF-8

`wchar_t` = DBCS, UTF-16 or UTF-32, depending on compiler/platform

`char8_t` = UTF-8

`char16_t` = UTF-16

`char32_t` = UTF-32

> Is wchar_t character or wchar_t string literal capable of storing UTF encodings?

Yes, UTF-16 or UTF-32, depending on compiler/platform.  In case of UTF-16, a single `wchar_t` can only hold a codepoint value that is in the BMP.  A single `wchar_t` in UTF-32 can hold any codepoint value.  A `wchar_t` string can encode all codepoints in either encoding.

> How to properly manipulate UTF strings (such as toupper/tolower conversion) and be compatible with locales simultaneously?

That is a very broad topic, worthy of its own separate question by itself.

Comment: Thank you for shedding light on this topic. I understand now how huge this topic really is. I need to ask one or two more extensive questions about that, but as you said, it is worth a separate question.

Comment: Nice write up. Minor point: You always could use so-called non-English characters in string literals. The compiler encodes them to the specific "execution charset" (encoding) as directed, with some compilers defaulting to UTF-8. This the case for `'x'` in the question.

Comment: @MooingDuck "*It's important to call out that `std::string` is `char` based (aka not multi-byte aware), and though it can _store_ multibyte data, all methods use `char` index and `char` length*" - the same can be said of any of the string types. They store encoded units, not Unicode codepoints. What people generally perceive as characters (ie graphemes) is not what string interfaces are designed for at the, you usually need higher level Unicode libraries to deal with those.

Comment: @MooingDuck "*you need to have outside knowledge beyond just the type*" - added